# How to navigate to C drive in bash on WSL-Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed bash on Ubuntu on Windows feature on Windows 10 and I want to change directory this path on my `C:\` drive:

```
C:/wamp64/www
```

What should I do ?

Comment: problem is that i don`t know how to write C drive`s path...
should i write it like   C:/the/directory

Answer (score 104, accepted):

#### `C:\` in Windows is `/mnt/c/` in WSL Ubuntu

In Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) The `C:\` drive is mounted as `/mnt/c/`, `D:\` is mounted as `/mnt/d/` et cetra. Therefore, `C:/wamp64/www` should be at `/mnt/c/wamp64/www`. Try:

```
cd /mnt/c/wamp64/www
```

in the Ubuntu terminal to go to that folder. Note, the first `/` before `mnt` and remember that in Ubuntu file and folder names are case sensitive. So `wamp64`, `WAMP64`, `wAmP64`, and `WaMp64` are 4 different folders! See https://superuser.com/questions/1116625/how-can-i-access-case-sensitive-paths-on-windows-created-with-bash-on-ubuntu-on for a bit more on using case sensitive file names in WSL.

#### Background on `/mnt`

Windows users not familiar with Ubuntu (Linux in general) may wonder:

**What does `/mnt` stand for?**

In Linux almost everything is a file or a folder. `/mnt` is a folder, `/mnt/c` is a folder called `c` inside the folder `/mnt`.

In Linux partitions (Windows calls them "drives" to confuse us) are **mounted** in folders generally called "mount points". So in WSL, the "C Drive" is mounted in the `c` folder inside `/mnt` folder. `/mnt`is a folder within which other folders are created for the purpose of mounting various partitions. See the link related to mnt below.

#### References:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/06/15/wsl-file-system-support/

https://superuser.com/questions/1066261/how-to-access-windows-folders-from-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows

**On `mnt`**

https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/mnt.html

Hope this helps

Comment: I memorize the commands when I understand them more -> `/mnt/c/` this `mnt` what dose it stand for?

Comment: @YousefAltaf in Linux almost everything is a file or a folder. `/mnt` is a folder, `/mnt/c` is a folder called `c` inside the folder `/mnt`. Partitions (Windows calls them "drives" to confuse us) are mounted in Linux in folders. So the "C Drive" is mounted in the `c` folder inside `/mnt` folder. [`/mnt`](http://www.linfo.org/mnt.html) is a folder within which other folders are created for the purpose of mounting various partitions.

Comment: Right `Partitions (Windows calls them "drives" to confuse us)` thanks for explanation

Comment: worked for me, thank you