# Directory locations when using WSL

Tags: directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cd-command, mkdir

I'm new to the Ubuntu world and I need some help. (Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, x64 system type)
I created a directory called "Submarine" using this :

```
mkdir Submarine
```

I want the directory "Submarine" to be located in "Documents" (as circled in red on

[image]

But the directory has been located in a whole other place

[image]

By the way, if I type :

```
cd Documents/
```

The terminal says that there's no such file or directory

[image]

What should I do to create files and directories in the place I want ?

Comment: please do not use images and copy the text that is important (ie. the directory you highlighted). That way we can copy/paste it  ;)

Comment: Likely a duplicate of several other questions.  For starters, check out *"[How to navigate to C drive in bash on WSL-Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/943006/1165986)"*, which was already a duplicate of *"[Can I change directory to a Windows drive in Ubuntu Bash on WSL?](https://askubuntu.com/q/831361/1165986)"*.  You'll see in those that you can use `/mnt/c` to access files on the C:\ drive under WSL.

Comment: Note:  Also, from looking at the search results, you are using WSL1, which stored its root filesystem in the user AppData.  Do not edit files in that path!  It can [cause corruption](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

Comment: Ah, now noticing that this is an old question that got bumped by Community Bot.  I recommend closing it as a duplicate, so that it doesn't get surfaced again by Community Bot after a few more years.  It's unlikely the OP is going to accept an answer or close it themselves since they haven't been on the site in almost 2 years.

Answer (score 0):

You have Windows Subsystem for Linux which runs Ubuntu, different from a dual-boot installation where you are running either the Windows OS or the Ubuntu OS. WSL stores anything you make into a directory somewhere under your User directory. That's why your directory placed under c:\Utilisateurs\Elève\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows...

Your Documents folder of Windows actually is c:\Utilisateurs\Elève\Documents .

Specifics on using WSL and creating files and directories are shown in https://superuser.com/questions/1127307/create-folder-from-windows-then-access-from-bash-in-windows-10-wsl