# How can I access directories of my computer?

Tags: command-line, bash

I installed Ubuntu and CDO. Now I am trying to locate my computer directories such as Desktop or Downloads but can't. From the terminal when I run `cd` and `ls` I only have two directories i.e `home` & `user(neema)`. Perhaps I am missing something very basic here. Could anyone kindly help me out with this?

[image]

Secondly, I am trying to work with CDO from the R terminal and getting this error; any idea where am getting wrong?

```
/c/Users/nkita/Downloads
/c/Users/nkita/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpI7HPZa/chunk-code-e65814f2c58.txt: line 2: cd: /mnt/d/time_series/: No such file or directory
/c/Users/nkita/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpI7HPZa/chunk-code-e65814f2c58.txt: line 6: cdo: command not
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put screenshots of the terminal. Always copy the text of the terminal and directly paste it [in your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1324231/edit). Then format the pasted text as `code` using the { } icon above the edit window.

Comment: Also only 1 question per question please.

Comment: It seems you're using WSL, i.e., Ubuntu on Windows. If that's the case, see [How to navigate to C drive in bash on WSL-Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943006/how-to-navigate-to-c-drive-in-bash-on-wsl-ubuntu). Also, IIRC, there's no Downloads folder by default on Ubuntu WSL (though you can create later on).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```bsh
cd /home/yourusername  # substitute your actual username
```

In Linux there is no `C:` drive, the `/` will get you to the root, and then you can find all you want

If you want it to look more like Windows then

```
sudo apt install gnome
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the later part is applicable here since I believe questioner is using Ubuntu WSL.